# Blinking an LED linked through Arduino-Python

Tags: arduino, pyserial

I wrote a sample code for blinking an LED linked to Python. The code is not throwing me any error, but the LED is not blinking. Any suggestions?

Python code:

```py
import serial #import the pyserial library
connected = False #this will represent whether or not ardunio is connected to the system
ser = serial.Serial("COM3",9600) #open the serial port on which Ardunio is connected to, this will coommunicate to the serial port where ardunio is connected, the number which is there is called baud rate, this will provide the speed at which the communication happens
while not connected:#you have to loop until the ardunio gets ready, now when the ardunio gets ready, blink the led in the ardunio
    serin = ser.read()
    connected = True
ser.write('1') #this will blink the led in the ardunio
while ser.read() == '1': #now once the led blinks, the ardunio gets message back from the serial port and it get freed from the loop!
    ser.read()
print('Program is done')
ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```cpp
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
 Serial.write('1');
}
void loop() {
 if(Serial.available()>0){
  digitalWrite(255,HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(50,LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(255,HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(50,LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(255,HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(50,LOW);
  Serial.read();
 }
 else{
  Serial.available()==0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the arduino code, you call

```
digitalWrite(50,LOW);
```

and

```
digitalWrite(255,HIGH);
```

but the first parameter of digitalWrite is the pin number, which you defined as pin 10. Simply change 50 and 255 to 10 as that is where you want your low and high signals to output to.